# arduino pressure sensor skips notes in melody C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, arduino

What the code is supossed to do is: when you press, it keeps playing note[0] until you stop putting pressure on it. Than the next time you press it, it plays note[1] until you stop pressuring it. Next press it plays note[2] until you stop pressuring it and so on. (note[] = mariomelody[])

Does anyone have a clue why it might not be working properly?

I do get different notes each time I put press it, but I've come to the conclusion that it keeps skipping notes.

My code:

```
int buttonPin = 12;
int buzzerPin = 8;

int ledPin = 7;
int pressurePin = A0;

void setup()
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT);
}


void loop()
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(mariomelody) / sizeof(mariomelody[0]); i++)
  {
     while (analogRead(pressurePin) < 200)
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }
    while (analogRead(pressurePin) > 250)
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      tone(buzzerPin, mariomelody[i], 20);
    }
  }
```

`mariomelody` is just an array of integers for frequencies that make the right sound. The array is 110% not the problem...

EDIT:

**Extra context:**
I press it. It makes a sound and I kinda hold it so the LED's are still lit, but the sound stops. When I press it a little harder again it plays a different note, but the LED's were lit the whole time.

Comment: Sounds (no pun intended) like your button is bouncing - you should debounce it.

Comment: I'm not using a button anymore though...

Comment: Is your pressure sensor bouncing / noisy then? Because the code is correct besides missing debouncing, except for one condition: if analogRead() returns a value between 200 and 250, you will increment your counter i without doing anything.

Comment: You last edit makes a debouncing issue look even more likely to be your problem. The led does not *seem* turn off, because it will be off for a duration too short for human perception.

Comment: I'm fairly new to using the arduino. So I'm supossed to debounce the pressure sensor? Do you have any tips on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You increment your counter when analogRead() returns something between 200 and 250 without playing a note. To fix this, use the same threshold on both calls (i.e. check for >200 and <=200 instead of >200 and <250).

Another possible issue is that your pressure sensor is bouncing. You could wrap your analogRead()s into functions like below to prevent this:

```
void read_dbnc_low(int pin)
{
  while (1) {
    if (analogRead(pin) < 200) {
      delay(1); // 1ms

      if (analogRead(pin) < 200) {
        delay(1);  // 1ms

        if (analogRead(pin) < 200) {
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void read_dbnc_high(int pin)
{
  while (1) {
    if (analogRead(pin) >= 200) {
      delay(1); // 1ms

      if (analogRead(pin) >= 200) {
        delay(1);  // 1ms

        if (analogRead(pin) >= 200) {
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And modify your for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(mariomelody) / sizeof(mariomelody[0]); i++)
{
  read_dbnc_low(pressurePin);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  read_dbnc_high(pressurePin);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  tone(buzzerPin, mariomelody[i], 20);
}
```

Comment: It says: "exit status 1
a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token". They're talking about the first '{' when the method starts.

Comment: You must put these functions outside (above) your main() function.

Comment: It works! Thanks! Now for making the sound last longer :D

Comment: Can I put `read_dbnc_low(pressurePin);` as parameter of a while loop so it keep playing until pressure is released?

Comment: Remove the last argument of tone() - so it's just *tone(buzzerPin, mariomelody[i])*. As the arduino reference says, the tone will play forever instead of just 20 milliseconds. See https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/tone/

Comment: Almost! But when i release the pressure it still plays and that's not the precise goal. I want it to only play when there's pressure. So while loop isn't possible?

Comment: It is. To stop playing once the pressure is released, add one line directly after *read_dbnc_low(pressurePin);*: **noTone(buzzerPin);**